# MVC Caching of frequently accessed data that would very infrequently change

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, caching

I'm new to the concept of caching data and I wanted to ask if there are any issues I"m overlooking with the strategy I"m building for caching data in my MVC web application from my database. I want to stress that basically the data I'm looking at caching is practically read only, and would only be updated very very infrequently (coinciding with code upgrades where the app would be being refreshed).

From what I have been able to research I was planning on using a static class to serve as a helper for building and maintaining the cache. The below code shows how I would build the cache from a database table which would contain the different baseball card condition grades (Mint, Near Mint, etc)

Static CacheHelper class:

```
public static class CacheHelpers
{
    private static HashSet<baseballcardcondition> _CardConditionsCache = null;
    public static HashSet<baseballcardcondition> CardConditionsCache
    {
        get
        {
            if (_CardConditionsCache == null)
            {
                _CardConditionsCache = (HttpContext.Current.Cache["CardConditionsCache"] as HashSet<baseballcardconditions>);
                if (_CardConditionsCache == null)
                {
                    mydbEntities db = new mydbEntities();
                    _CardConditionsCache = new HashSet<baseballcardconditions>(db.baseballcardconditions);
                    HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert("CardConditionsCache", _CardConditionsCache);
                }
            }
            return _CardConditionsCache;
        }
        set
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert("CardConditionsCache", _CardConditionsCache);
        }
    }//public static HashSet<baseballcardconditions> CardConditionsCache
}//public static class CacheHelpers
```

Later I would be using this data to build a formatted string for a jqGrid grid (a jQuery javascript plugin for displaying tabular data) and would access it via:

```
        //cardConditionSelectListHelperString
        string tempString = "";

        foreach (var keyPair in CacheHelpers.CardConditionsCache)
        {
            tempString += keyPair.IdBaseballCardCondition + ":" + keyPair.Condition + ";";
        }
```

Does this look like a solid, robust, and thread safe way to manage my cache for my MVC web application? I would probably expand my CacheHelpers class to have other cached Hashsets so I don't have to hit the database for this read only, basically static data.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

"Does this look like a solid, robust, and thread safe way to manage my cache for my MVC web application? "

No, it doesn't. For example how do you keep the size of your data low? You should flush the unused data from the cache (check this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd632018.aspx). In addition it is not thread safe.

I think create an own cache solution is the typical "re-inviting the wheel" scenario, there are a lot of cache (even distributed cache) on the market - in addition some of them are free. A good cache solution is much more complex than just start using some static field.

Comment: The data that would be stored in the cache is basically used on every page view and would never be out of date short of me rebuilding the application.